# I would like to run a shell script to parse a dynamic log file in a folder and search for the keyword error on the latest logfile

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep, echo

I'm currently moving from Windows administrator to Linux. I'm trying to monitor a folder when there will be new log files created everyday.

For example:

```
log-02-17-2023
log-02-18-2023
```

How can we figureout the latest file using the modified time of the file in that folder and after finding the latest log file I would want it to parse that file and search for the keyword error.

I kind of have something written in perl, but its still in progress. Is it possible to execute the *.sh file and it should show me the parsed output of that keyword error and the line number and echo/print the complete line containing the error as an output from the latest file. Is it possible?

If I do this I can get it to display the file names that has this keyword error, but I would also want it to display the keywork error line as well as it should pick only the latest logfile.

```
$ find /var/monitor/ -type f -name "*" -exec grep -l "error" {} \+ 2>/dev/null
```

Output:

```
/var/monitor/logfile
/var/monitor/logfile-16022023
```

Is it possible to get any simple sh script doing this process? I know this is not a code donating forums but it would be greatly appreciable for any quick help and I promise to mark the answer immediately. Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove the `-l` (learn to read `man grep`, `man find` (that will take a while!). Getting the lastest file may work with `ls -1tr /path/to/logs/log* | tail -1` but that is fragile so avoid files and paths that aren't just plain alpha-numeric chars (no spaces!). Learn about `command-substition` with `$( myCmd )`.  Your above cah be a shell script just by putting it in a file and adding `#!/bin/bash` as the first line. Good luck.

Comment: What's the point of `-name '*'`? There doesn't exist any name it _won't_ be true for. And you don't need to escape `+`

Comment: And see [BashFAQ #3](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) re: finding the newest or oldest file. Relying on `ls` is deeply unreliable for multiple reasons -- see [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), but also keep in mind that `-exec ... {} +` can require multiple invocations after the list of names becomes too long, and those invocations' results are only _individually_ sorted.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Possibly not relevant to this question, but the bashfaq methods don't guarantee that the same file will be consistently returned if multiple files are the "latest". Perhaps amusingly, my /var/log currently contains two such files (both have mtime 1676666338.3233788580): `ls -rt` and `find ...%T@...|sort` produce different orderings.

Comment: @jhnc, do you have GNU sort handy? IIRC, there's a "stable" mode available behind a flag.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I do but I'm not sure it's relevant: if `ls -rt` returns (say) three files as `b`, `c`, `a`, then it doesn't matter how stable the sort is, the order will be different (`a`, `b`, `c`). bashfaq#3 does say not to use `ls` but the first two methods it provides have equivalent "failure" mode

Comment: If all three of a, b, and c have the same timestamp in the first column followed by the filename in the second column, then yes, sort will return a, b, c in that order... but I'm clearly misunderstanding something about how that's not going to consistently return the same file as newest, since you _do_ have a consistent ordering (primary key is timestamp, secondary key is name, so you have stability in which key sorts as first)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I was looking at the method using `-nt`. I'm wrong. I forgot that globs are sorted. So results should indeed be repeatable. (But the version using `-nt` still gives a different result from the `sort -r` version:  You get `a` for the former and `c` for the latter)

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

`ls -dlst /var/monitor/* | awk '{print $10}' | xargs grep -s "error" | head -1`

To put it in a `shell.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd="ls -dlst /var/monitor/* | awk '{print $10}' | xargs grep -s "error" | head -1"
bash -c $cmd
```

Comment: this command when run directly on the terminal it works fine. How do I add this to a shell.sh file and make the .sh file to run successfully?

Comment: Did you try adding it to a `shell.sh` file? If it works on the command line, it should work in shell script too.

Comment: when I try running the script as # sh shell.sh it gives all the files names alone as an output. It doesnt show the same output as just running the command. Not sure why when running the above script on a shell.sh file it doesnt work.

Comment: Can you try putting single quotes around `error` word in line `xargs grep -s "error"` and then try please?

Comment: If you store the command in a double-quoted string and then invoke it, the `$10` will probably turn into `0`. Why are you storing the command in a string in the first place?

Comment: `cmd="ls stuff | more stuff"; bash -c $cmd` just runs `ls` (with no arguments)

Comment: @hacker315 To be clear, `bash -c "$cmd"` would be less wrong. It's still wrong, though, because the cmd gets munged during the assignment. (Try `printf '%s\n' "$cmd"` and compare its output to what you think _should_ be in cmd)